# NFC - how to launch the app using NDEF_DISCOVERED

Tags: android, nfc

I am writing an application that is supposed to detect nfc tag and automatically be launched.
I have succeeded in doing so by using TECH_DISCOVERED + filters but I think the better way to do it is by using NDEF_DISCOVERED.
I have added the intent-filter to my manifest but it doesn't work.
This is my manifest code for the TECH_DISCOVERED, that works:

```
    <intent-filter>    
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"    
     android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

when I want to try the NDEF_DISCOVERED i try:

```
                <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

for the tags, I use 'Mifare classic 1k' tags that was written as 'Smart Poster' using NFC TagInfo app from the market.

What am I doing wrong?
or, what is another way to make my app be launched and not show the activity selection dialog?

Thanks,
Eran.

Comment: Here is a sample application that will launch based on scanning a tag with a URL of http://commonsware.com/nfctest: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/NFC/URLTagger -- I have not tried using `android:mimeType` as an NFC tag trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are filtering for text/plain and not the URI of the smart poster. Android converts smart posters to URIs, then you have to filter for that URI. You can see the URI in logcat if you check for the intent that is started. For a URI like http://example.com/file, do something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/file" />
</intent-filter>
```

See the NFC dev guide for more information on how to parse NDEF messages. Please read the entire document to fully understand how to filter for the right intent: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: Hi,I tried what you told me here. i have looked at the logcat and don't see ( or don't know how) the URI for that tag.<br> i can see the data in the tag which is a url.  can you advise?  thanks

Comment: Yes, the data element should be the URI. Try filtering for that with the example intent filter above, modifying it for the URI that you see. If that doesn't work, post the data element information here, and I might be able to help further.

Comment: thanks.it still doesn't work. this is what i see using NFC TagInfo app.( ftom the market): WELL-KNOWN:irn:nfc:wkt:Sp (Smart Poster), WELL-KNOWN:urn:nfc:wkt:U (URI)     Identifier:0x01("Http://www.") "imdb.com"                  That's what i have here.  Thanks for your quick help!!!

Comment: Can you post the logcat output that has the URI?

Comment: i took the relevant line:"{ act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED flg=0x13000000 cmp=eran.study.movies/.NMoviesActivity (has extras) }"

Comment: Was that the only intent that was started? Was there an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent before that? If not, this means that Android could not parse the smart poster, which means you have to filter for TECH_DISCOVERED. It seems like the smart poster was not in the correct NDEF format as specified by the NFC Forum if the only intent started is TECH_DISCOVERED.

Comment: indeed, there are no other intents except TECH_DISCOVERED. the tag was written using one of the apps in the market..  so you say it wasn't written correctly as a smart poster?   actually i would like thhat my app will be open on any tag(with my data) in the future.. i know the on android 4.0 it would be possible using AAR.. but how to do it now?   i am using TECH_DISCOVERED now.. but i don't know how to get it open my app without the intent chooser..   ?

Comment: Yes, either the smart poster was written incorrectly, or its a bug with how Android parses the tag. I would play around with maybe a different type of tag and see if the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent is started. Do something simple like a plain text record only, using the filter that you have originally in your question. If that works, try some other type. If that works, try a different smart poster. Unfortunately, filtering for tech_discovered is harder to guarantee that your app is started without the intent chooser. Try a different tag writing app. I don't think I can help much more besides this.

Comment: Thanks.. you helped a lot.. you gave me some directions. i will try simple text... thanks again.

Comment: man, you are a genious! it worked! i used plain text and my app was opened. thanks!